# Finding other Players position with a Fabric mod client

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

How can I get player positions from other players on a server using a minecraft fabric client in 1.18.1?

Comment: What makes you think that it is possible? I ask because it seems plausible to me that this info is intentionally unavailable; think PVP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can, only with players that are in render distance though.

How I'd implement this is by:

1. On every tick, use the getEntities method of the ClientWorld class
2. Check for instances of playerentities, and get their positions using getPos or something else

You can't grab the positions of every player on the server unfortunately though